# not able to print contents of sql table in python using pretty table

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector, prettytable

```
import os
import time
import mysql.connector as ms
from prettytable import from_db_cursor

mydb=ms.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="12345")   
mycursor=mydb.cursor()
x=input("DATABASE NAME : ")
mycursor.execute("show databases")
result=mycursor.fetchall()

if (x,) in result:
    mydb=ms.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="12345",database=x)
    mycursor=mydb.cursor()
    if mydb.is_connected():
        print("...........connection established.............")
else:
    print("no database")

def display():
    mycursor.execute("select * from student")
    result=mycursor.fetchall()
    print("""
    no OF RECORDS IS: """,mycursor.rowcount)
    print("""
              """)
    if mycursor.rowcount>0:
        x = from_db_cursor(mycursor)
        print(x)
    else:
        print("the table is empty")

display()
```

while executing
i am getting the following table
but it dont have any contents in it
which i saved in the table
it just shows heading of the tables only
please help me with this

## [image: this is what i get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `from_db_cursor()` function uses the `fetchall()` method. You can find it [here](https://github.com/jazzband/prettytable/blob/master/src/prettytable/prettytable.py#L2400-L2406).

But since we have a `fetchall()` in line 22 (i.e., below the query execution in display( ) function), there's nothing left to fetch after that. So, to get the rows again, you'd have to execute the same query again (without another `fetchall()`).

So, the new display( ) should look like:

```py
def display():
    mycursor.execute("select * from student")
    result=mycursor.fetchall()
    print("""
    no OF RECORDS IS: """,mycursor.rowcount)
    print("""
              """)
    if mycursor.rowcount>0:
        mycursor.execute("select * from student")
        x = from_db_cursor(mycursor)
        print(x)
    else:
        print("the table is empty")
```

You may read more about fetchall() [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html).